# Biopython print command prints only the first 25 records parsed, I want to see all

Tags: parsing, biopython

I am parsing a multi-fasta file using Biopython. The "print" command displays the first 25 records on the screen, but I know the file contains more records. I want to see them all. Is 25 a default limit? How can I instruct Biopython to display all the records?

I apologize for not including the code earlier. I am using Python 2.7.9, Biopython 1.66 and Numpy 1.9.1.

First, I'm just counting how many records.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
filename = "myFileNameHere.fasta"
count = 0
for record in SeqIO.parse(filename, "fasta"):
    count = count + 1

print "there are " + str(count) + " records"
```

Structured this way, it prints that there are 50 records in the file.

But if I put the print statement -- print str(count) -- inside the loop, it prints to the screen a series from 1 to 25 like so
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
24
25

Why does it stop at 25 if there are 50 records in the file?

Next I ask to see the id and length.

```
for record in SeqIO.parse(filename, "fasta"):
    print "record " + record.id + ", length " + str(len(record.seq))
```

It prints the info, but only 25 records. So I thought, hmmm, only 25 displayed each time I ask for a display? Default limit of 25?

Comment: does this `for seq in SeqIO.parse("m.fasta", "fasta"): print seq` print 25 for you?

Comment: You need to explain what you were doing in more detail, i.e. the lines of code used to load and print the FASTA file. It would also help to mention the version of Python and version of Biopython.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. I have added the code and versions.

Comment: You code should print all the records in the fasta file. Can you open the fasta file and count how many ">" are at the start of line? In linux, you can do grep "^>" tt | wc -l

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the same file both times?

Comment: Azalea, thank you! There are, indeed, only 25 records in the fasta. So it is the portion of the code that generated the number 50 that is the problem. Since 50 is 2 x 25, maybe it counted twice. I had the print statement inside the loop at first, and then put it outside the loop. Maybe I didn't include the zero-ing step to clear the counter before running the code again. Maybe it counted to 25 and then continued counting to 50. Will check to see if I can get it to produce 75 and 100 on repeat runs. But at least the more basic steps are correct. Thanks!

Comment: PeterJC, yes, looking at the same file both times. Maybe just running the code twice without zero-ing the counter. I was assuming that the count of 50 was correct and the other parts were wrong. But the 50 part was the wrong part. Thanks.